# Using Spring Data JPA with Spring 3.1.0

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-data-jpa

Does anyone have an idea how I can use Spring Data JPA and use Spring 3.1.0/3.1.1?

Spring Data JPA 1.0.3 depends on spring 3.0.5 so as soon as I add a spring data jpa as a dependency I get a conflict as I'm using 3.1.0.

I've tried using maven excludes but have had not had much success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am successfully integrating Spring Data JPA 1.0.3 with Spring 3.1.0. Here is a stripped `pom.xml` that looks fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Looking at transitive dependencies, everything seems OK:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
    com.example:example:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
+- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
|  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
|     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:test (scope not updated to compile)
\- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile
   +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons-core:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
   +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
   +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:runtime
   \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.8:compile
```

What kind of conflicts do you have?

Comment: Yes, you get a lot of: `org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.1.0.RELEASE` - which is fine, maven choses newer or explicitly declared dependency. Feature, not a bug :-). Your final artifact will use newer versions.